# Stenciljs @State() not working for Key:Value pairs

Tags: javascript, typescript, state, stenciljs, stencil-component

I have a Key: Value pair object in my Stenciljs project with the @State() decorator so the components re-render when one or more of the values are updated but the re-rendering does not happen. my object looks like this:

`@State() selected: {[key: string]: string} = {x: "", y: "", z: ""};`

I update it the following way: `this.selected['x'] = newValue;`

I know the object is being updated when desired and there are no errors coming up.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post a minimal, reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Stencil docs:

> mutating an object will not trigger a view update in Stencil, but
> returning a new copy of the object will

So you need to treat your `selected` object as immutable:

```
this.selected = {...this.selected, x: newValue};
```